# Unable to import xlrd module Python 3.60

Tags: xlrd

Good day,
I get the following error when importing xlrd. Does any one get this?

```
import xlrd
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    import xlrd
  File "C:\Users\irwin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 1187
    print "EXTERNSHEET(b7-):"
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Looks like you have Python 2 version installed. How did you install `xlrd`?

Comment: I reinstalled it. Thanks

Comment: @IrwinMooketsiChelenyane So did that solve your problem?